# SN74HC595 Shift Register Issue

Tags: arduino-mega, shift-register, error

I'm trying to use the popular SN74HC595 Shift Register, but I think something isn't right because when the bits are submitted to the register it comes out with something similar but not the same.

```c
#define Latch 9
#define CLK 10
#define DATA 8

byte led = B10110111;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(Latch, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATA, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(Latch, LOW);
  shiftOut(DATA, CLK, MSBFIRST, led);
  digitalWrite(Latch, HIGH);
}

void loop() 
{
  //LOOP
}
```

After this completes I receive an output of 10110101 instead of 10110111. Has anybody had the same area? Any fixes? Could my chip be faulty inside?

Schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: is a specific bit failing?

Comment: I guess you have just forgotten to draw the gnd and 5V lines to the breadboard?

Comment: Lack of decoupling capacitors?

Comment: @jsotola It can be any bit that fails but usually within the last 3

Comment: @Wirewrap Yes I forgot to draw the GND, and 5V to the breadboard, but they are connected

Comment: I so not know if this helps, but I had a similar "random data" problem with my shift register. It turned out that there wasn't a tight connection between one of the data in/enable pins and VCC. So I made sure all my jumpers were firm in the breadboard (bent the pins just a tiny bit) and tried another breadboard.

Comment: I'm with Magenko, you need  a 0.1uF cap from the shift register's Vcc pin to the nearest Gnd.  I've strung up 9, 18, 27, 36, 45 shift registers and clocked in data a 8 MHz use SPI and not had issues. Check your connections and add a cap.  Make sure the clear pin is pulled high and the output enable pin is pullled low.